# Smart way to map knotty json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have below json and I'm looking for smart way to map this for java object. Till now I tried this way, but it didnt helped.

JSON:https://pastebin.com/NBCGXgUD

This is what i tried

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TravelpayoutsResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private TravelpayoutsData data;
    private String error;
    private String currency;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TravelpayoutsData {
    private FlightDetails flightDetails[];
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FlightDetails {
private FlightDetail[] flightDetails;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FlightDetail {
    private int price;
    private String airline;
    @JsonProperty("flight_number")
    private String flightNumber;
    @JsonProperty("departure_at")
    private String departureDate;
    @JsonProperty("return_at")
    private String returnDate;
    @JsonProperty("expires_at")
    private String expirationDate;
}
```

But it didnt worked for me. Maybe do you have any idea how to map it? I would be very thankfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any arrays in the JSON.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TravelpayoutsResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private Map<String, Map<String, FlightDetail> data;
    private String error;
    private String currency;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FlightDetail {
    private int price;
    private String airline;
    @JsonProperty("flight_number")
    private String flightNumber;
    @JsonProperty("departure_at")
    private String departureDate;
    @JsonProperty("return_at")
    private String returnDate;
    @JsonProperty("expires_at")
    private String expirationDate;
}
```